# invalid index to scalar variable error in solve of system of 5 ode in python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter, ode, triangular

I wrote the following code to solve 5 differential equations in Python.
But I get the following error:
invalid index to scalar variable
I was very tried and searched, but I did not find that where is it?
Can anyone tell me where should I fix?

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
def ode(x, t):
    vx = x[0]
    vy = x[1]
    x = x[2]
    y = x[3]
    a = x[4]
    dvxdt = -0.2*(np.cos(a))/(x**2+y**2)
    dvydt = -0.2*(np.sin(a))/(x**2+y**2)
    dxdt = vx
    dydt = vy
    dadt = (x*vy - y*vx)*((np.cos(a))**2)/(x**2)
    return [dvxdt, dvydt, dxdt, dydt, dadt]
x0 = [-1.7, 1, 5, 2, 0.5]
t = np.linspace(0,15,1000)
x = odeint(ode,x0,t)
vx = x[:,0]
vy = x[:,1]
x = x[:,2]
y = x[:,3]
a = x[:,4]

plt.semilogy(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: When you report an error on stackoverflow, it is helpful to include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line in the function `ode`:

```
    x = x[2]
```

You have reassigned the variable `x`, so after this statement is executed, `x` is the scalar that had been stored in the original array `x`.  You'll have to use a different name for the scalar or for the `ode` array parameter.

You have a similar problem later in the script:

```
x = x[:,2]
```